# How does One Disable the Undo/Redo Functions for a Textbox?

Tags: c#, .net

I am having what I believe to be a memory leak within an application I am developing. Using JetBrains DotMemory, I have found a very large number of strings and chars stemming from TextBoxBase.get_text(). Upon further investigation, I have found reports of memory leaks in regards to the textbox's stack (which enables the undo/redo functionalities). Furthermore, many SO users have said to use TextBoxBase.IsUndoEnabled.. but this is not recognized as a property in my Visual Studio (2019). I am using .NET 4.7.2 and a quick google does show the property listed in MSDN documentation. I am now aware that a textbox may simply not be the tool for the job, however, I am eager to figure out the exact reasoning for my memory leak... How can I disable the Undo/Redo feature of a textbox in Windows Forms Applications (.NET Framework)? If I set the textbox ReadOnly property to true, is this sufficient? While I am here, I figured I would include what I believe to be my offending piece of code.. any and all comments, questions and/or concerns are beyond appreciated, thank you. (and hooray for my first SO question).

```
        _LineBuilder.LineBuilt += (o, e) => {

            if (PortForm.initial_connection_happened) {
                /* FW Tester Appendage */
                raw_fw_data_tb.InvokeIfRequired(() => {
                    raw_fw_data_tb.AppendText(String.Concat(e.line, "\r\n"));
                    /* Gets rid of old data for memory sakes. */
                    if (raw_fw_data_tb.Lines.Length > 10000) {
                        /* Get rid of first 9000 lines, keeping the last 1000 */
                        for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {
                            int count = raw_fw_data_tb.Lines[0].Length;
                            raw_fw_data_tb.Text = raw_fw_data_tb.Text.Remove(0, count + Environment.NewLine.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    raw_fw_data_tb.SelectionStart = raw_fw_data_tb.Text.Length;
                    raw_fw_data_tb.ScrollToCaret();
                });
```

I have not tried to set the ReadOnly property to true because it takes a considerable amount of time for my program to act up.

Comment: Your memory-leak is far more likely because the C# code you've posted so far is **very inefficient** because it generates thousands of new immutable `String` objects. Yikes.

Comment: Also, you say you're on .NET 4.7.2 - but 4.8.1 is the minimum version now.

Comment: The `IsUndoEnabled` property is for WPF's `System.Windows.Controls.TetBoxBase` _not_ WinForms' `System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase`. For WinForms, there's no way to disable Undo, but you can call `ClearUndo()` within the `TextChanged` event, I suppose.

Comment: @Dai Thanks so much for your input. May I ask, what exactly is the new immutable String object..? Is it the String.Concat(...)? If so, how would I go about passing e.line to the AppendText method with a new line without creating an immutable object?

In regards to the .NET, I use 4.7.2 because the rest of the development at my company is being done with this Framework.. if you go to MSDN, you will find the property in the .NET 4.7.2 Framework... which is odd but.. trivial compared to the rest of my wonders...

Comment: @Dai Also, as I kind of eluded to in my post, the memory leak is in unmanaged memory and the end node of the trace is TextBoxBase.Get_text()

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this to get rid of the first 9,000 lines:

```
raw_fw_data_tb.AppendText(String.Concat(e.line, "\r\n"));
if (raw_fw_data_tb.Lines.Length > 10000)
{
    raw_fw_data_tb.Lines = (new List<String>(raw_fw_data_tb.Lines)).Skip(9000).ToArray();
}
raw_fw_data_tb.SelectionStart = raw_fw_data_tb.Text.Length;
raw_fw_data_tb.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I am going to try this and get back to you as soon as I can.